# can't rotate the uploaded image using php

Tags: php

I try to rotate the uploaded image 90 degrees after uploading, I tried `imagerotate()` method, but it's not working.

Here is my code:

```
$tmp = $_FILES['photoimg']['tmp_name']; 
$path = "uploads/";  
move_uploaded_file($tmp, $path."newfile.jpg");  
$rotate = imagerotate($path."newfile.jpg", 90, 0);
imagejpeg($rotate);
imagedestroy($source);
imagedestroy($rotate);
```

Any help will be greately appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

[imagerotate](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagerotate.php) needs a resource as first parameter not a file path. You should get an error if you'd enable error reporting. `error_reporting(E_ALL);`

```
$source = imagecreatefromjpeg($path."newfile.jpg");
$rotate = imagerotate($source, 90, 0);
imagejpeg($rotate);
imagedestroy($source);
imagedestroy($rotate);
```